# Free translating tools have comparing view between source and translation?

Tags: translation

MemoQ and Trados have this feature, but the free tool OmegaT doesn't:

[image]

So in the segmentation panel the source and the translation are separated.

Requirements:

- Windows software
- Free
- Works with .docx and .html

Comment: Google translate?

Comment: but it doesn't have segmentation